# Last items won't have an absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been teaching myself HTML/CSS and realized CSS positioning has stumped me. (It is containing 4 sections, labeled 1-4.) I can get sections 1-3 to absolute position themselves to the top of the relative container body, but section 4 refuses to absolute position itself.

However, if I move section 4 after section 2 in the HTML (so it isn't last), it works fine. So basically, just the last section will not work. Sorry if this is confusing.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
}

section {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#section3 {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#section4 {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">Section 1</section>
<section id="section2">Section 2</section>
<section id="section3">Section 3</section>
<section id="section4">Section 4</section>
```

Comment: You can add `top:0;` to `#section4` styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes and here is the explanation. You can add `position: absolute` to `section` in the CSS so all the `<section>` in the HTML have absolute positioning.

When you put `position: relative` in `#section1`, `#section2`, `#section3`, and `#section4`, you changed the positioning of `<section>` from `absolute` to `relative`, and you don't want to do that in this case.

Once you have that, then you can play around with the `top, bottom, left, right` to see how each `<section>` stacks on each other.

I have `section1` at 0px from top , 0px from left relative to the container.

`section2` at 20px from top, 20px from left relative to the container.

`section3` at 40px from top, 40px from left relative to the container.

`section4` at 60px from top, 60px from left relative to the container.

Because we don't define z-index, so in the HTML code the later `<section>` will be on top of the previous `<section>`.

```css
body
{
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
}

section {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
}

#section1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#section2 {
    background-color: red;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
#section3 {
    background-color: green;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}
#section4 {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: white;
    top: 60px;
    left: 60px;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>UNDERSTANDING POSITIONING</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>  
<body>
    <section id="section1">Section 1</section>
    <section id="section2">Section 2</section>
    <section id="section3">Section 3</section>
    <section id="section4">Section 4</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to place each child element to a specific *absolute* location, try making their parent element `<body>` `relative` and the children `<section>` `absolute`. Then specify their `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` values.

```css
body
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#section1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#section2 {
    background-color: red;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}
#section3 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
#section4 {
    background-color: aqua;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>UNDERSTANDING POSITIONING</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>  
<body>
    <section id="section1">Section 1</section>
    <section id="section2">Section 2</section>
    <section id="section3">Section 3</section>
    <section id="section4">Section 4</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did have the body set at position: relative. I was just experimenting, assuming that as I set each section to position: absolute, they would go to the top left corner of the screen. All sections 1-3 will do this with no problem except the last one (section 4). Thanks for reading through this! I appreciate it!